# How to include file in heroku but not github

Tags: github, heroku, discord

I am making a discord bot and trying to host it on Heroku.  I am deploying from github and it deploys fine.  I only have one problem:  the discord bot logs in with an auth token that must be kept secret, so not on the repo, but is required for the bot to log in.  Does anyone know of a way to have a file not on the repo, but on the heroku app?

Edit:  I forgot to mention this initially, but I am using node.js and discord.io, thought that might be helpful.

Comment: use the config variable https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use environment variables on Heroku. If you have a password, you can save it in a file like this (assuming your programming language is Python):

```
import os
...
PASSWORD = os.environ['PASSWORD']
```

Then, in the Heroku CLI you can run the following:

```
heroku config:set PASSWORD=mypassword1234
```

This way you don't have to store credentials in a file.

Comment: Side note since the OP makes no mention of Python, I recommend [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) over `os.environ` since you can provide a fallback value. With `os.environ` if the `PASSWORD` variable doesn't exist you'll get a `KeyError`.

Comment: I'm a tad late on this, but i just got a random notification that took me back to this post, and I realized that this is the correct answer. Thanks!

Also, for node.js, which I was using in the OP, you would use `process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME`